# comparing the second element in a list of tuples

Tags: string, compare, tuples, python-3.7

Learning python here.

In this exercise the input is of the form [('Alice', 'R'), ('Bob', 'B'), ('Claire', 'R'), ('Dave', 'R'), ('Elsa', 'B')] whereby each element represents a person and the colour hat they wear (red or blue).

I need to compare the colours of the hats. How do I do that? Is there a way to slice the list such that I compare one person's hat to the other without losing track of their order and who wears what?

Comment: You said "python" in your question, but it would also be extremely useful if you "tagged" Python as well.  Since I don't know if you're using Python 2.7 or Python 3 (nor do I know if it would make a difference in this case), I took the liberty of guessing "Python 3".  And yes, you *can* "slice" Python tuples: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/.  And no, I wasn't the toad who marked you down (without saying "why")

Comment: I'm new to python, I'm also new to stack overflow. AFAIK I did tag it with python, I'm looking at the tag "python-3x". Let me know if that wasn't what I was supposed to do.

Comment: @n00b.py everyone can see from Edit History that paulsm4 added the tag python-3x and after that you added python-3.7. I would recommend you to always post what code you tried in your question for us to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

OK: Here's an example:

```
people = [('Alice', 'R'), ('Bob', 'B'),
          ('Claire', 'R'), ('Dave', 'R'), ('Elsa', 'B')]

redhats = [item for item in people if item[1] == 'R']

# printing output
print(redhats)
```